# Highland streams 'drain' event equivalent

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, highland.js

In `Node.js` writable streams we can detect buffering and temporarily stop writing to the stream until `drain` event occurs.

What's the way to learn that `Highland` stream was resumed, so that we can continue writing to it without buffering?